# A What/Who am I riddle

Tags: riddle

A very easy puzzle for the puzzlers here:

> I am found in the sea and on land but I do not walk or swim.
> I travel by foot but I am toeless.

#### Who/What am I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is probably

> A **snail**

---

I am found in the sea and on land but I do not walk or swim.

> There are normal snails, and also [sea snails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_snail), but snails neither walk nor swim.

I travel by foot but I am toeless.

> [Snails have one big foot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_snail#Physical_characteristics) but no toes

Comment: Very fast (like always). Right answer.

Comment: I was thinking either waves or the tide. They go out to see and they come onto land, and they are often measured by the foot

Comment: @AnthonyIngram-Westover also I nice thought! Probably a bit of a stretch on the foot part though

Answer (score 3):

Beastly Gerbil's answer is most likely correct, but I was thinking:

> Algae

I am found in the sea and on land but I do not walk or swim.

> Contrary to popular belief, algae can be found on land, and they most certainly don't walk or swim.

I travel by foot but I am toeless.

> This is a reference to the anchors that many algae possess, which is sometimes called a "foot".

Comment: Very Nice answer.